# Annotation InitBinder is not calling

Tags: java, spring

in my app I have controller:

```
package org.sample.web.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.sample.model.Contact;
import org.sample.model.Person;
import org.sample.model.PersonGender;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import ch.ralscha.extdirectspring.generator.IncludeValidation;
import ch.ralscha.extdirectspring.generator.ModelGenerator;
import ch.ralscha.extdirectspring.generator.OutputFormat;

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class ModelController {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        logger.error("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        binder.registerCustomEditor(PersonGender.class, new EnumPropertyEditor(PersonGender.class));
    }

    @RequestMapping("/app/model/Person.js")
    public void user(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ModelGenerator.writeModel(request, response, Person.class, OutputFormat.EXTJS4, IncludeValidation.ALL, true);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/app/model/Contact.js")
    public void catalog(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ModelGenerator.writeModel(request, response, Contact.class, OutputFormat.EXTJS4, IncludeValidation.ALL, true);
    }

}
```

problem is that method with annotation InitBinder is never calling so when I want to validate my enut it throws exception:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: org.sample.model.PersonGender.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:772)
```

EDIT:

```
PersonGender:

package org.sample.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum PersonGender implements Serializable {

  MALE("M"), FEMALE("F"), UNKNOWN("0");

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private static Map<String, PersonGender> identifierMap = new HashMap<String, PersonGender>();

    static {
        for (PersonGender value : PersonGender.values()) {
            identifierMap.put(value.getValue(), value);
        }
    }

    private String value;

    private PersonGender(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static PersonGender fromValue(String value) {
        PersonGender result = identifierMap.get(value);
        if (result == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No PersonGender for value: " + value);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

EXCEPTIon occurs when submiting form:

```
@Service
public class SimpleService {
...
    @ExtDirectMethod(value = ExtDirectMethodType.FORM_POST, group = "person")
    public ExtDirectFormPostResult validatePersonForm(@Valid Person p, BindingResult result) {
        if (!result.hasErrors()) {
            // another validations
        }
        return new ExtDirectFormPostResult(result);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Have you have any Validation annotation on `PersonGender`? Can you update your question with the `PersonGender` source code?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan nope. I updated question

Comment: You haven't set a validator for the `WebDataBinder`, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html#setValidator(org.springframework.validation.Validator)

Comment: what you mean with set a validator ?

Comment: this doesnt help me because whole method is not calling

Comment: Can you tell us which Controller method this exception occurs on? And show `writeModel` as well. InitBinders are supposed to be used with Command objects, but your methods don't have any.

Comment: none. This exception occurs when I submit form and this method is in @Service

Comment: In what class is the `validatePersonForm` method you posted?

Comment: @Service
public class SimpleService

Comment: There's your problem. A class annotated with `@Service` knows nothing about an `@InitBinder`, that's why it won't be called. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715860/why-is-my-spring-3-validator-validating-everything-on-the-model). Have the `@Valid PersonGender` as a controller method parameter.

Comment: oh I think that InitBinder should be always in Controler thx a lot

Comment: Sure, let us know if it worked out.